# Sparklines - Static Data Range

Tags: excel, sparklines

I have a workbook which I insert a column in the Column H field on a daily basis. The data inserted is for records of the previous day.

I know by defining a formula in "Name Manager" I can add more columns and my formula will be static.

Example: I sum all data points for the month.

```
Formula_1 = " =SUM('Sheet 1'!H$6:$AK$6) "
    When I add a new column in Column H then my formula includes this newly created column and shifts the second part of the reference to
```

$A$**L**6.

I have a Sparkline to show trends of my data. Every time I enter a new column I have to reconfigure the Sparkline "Data Range" to include my new column in the Column H field.

Is there a way I can have my Sparkline include my newly created column and shift my formula one cell to the right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By putting your data in a table it automatically recalculates and readjusts whenever you add or remove a column or row.

As a table your data looks like this:
[image]

Then when I add a column and insert numbers, the sum column moves to E column and the function becomes `=SUM(A2:D2)`

Hope this helps.